# Strange behaviour of mean() in python dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

I have found this weird behaviour of mean function in pandas dataframes, basically given a dataframe "d", a column "x" `d.mean()[x] != d[x].mean()`, here is a reproduction of this behaviour:

```
from sklearn.datasets import  load_diabetes
import pandas as pd

data = load_diabetes()
df = pd.DataFrame(data.data, columns=data.feature_names)

print(df.mean()['age'])
#-1.4442946587318214e-18
print(df['age'].mean())
#-2.511816797794472e-19
```

There is any known explanation for this?

Comment: Difference is interesting, Also surprising is I get closer but different values when I run your code: `(df.mean()['age']) of -3.6342849293088766e-16`, and `df['age'].mean() of -3.6396225400041895e-16`.  Using Python version 3.8.3 with Pandas 1.2.0

Comment: @DarrylG give a look to my comment below...

Comment: My previous comment used a Jupyter notebook.  I get the same result as Jupyter when running from the terminal.

Comment: I can confirm, both terminal and jupyter give this results to me, there seems to be two problems: the first is that Pycharm give totally wrong results and the second is that mean() gives different results depending on where you make the call...

Comment: `math.fsum(df['age'])/df.shape[0] results in -3.6356095201983384e-16` given yet another value after two decimal places.  [math.fsum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html) is supposedly more accurate but a more expensive computation.

Answer (score 1):

in my case it works correctly. I share my results

[image]

Comment: This is igetting more and more weird, I've just executed this code in my python console and I got same results as @DarryIG, but when I run the same code on PyCharm i get the values showed previously...

Comment: You are right. Pycharm returns your results

Comment: I can say that this isn't a problem regarding pandas, I've checked the mean "manually" with a loop, same results... This seems to be a problem of precision with PyCharm.